# Fireworks: Can I set a transparent fill color but solid stroke?

Tags: adobe-fireworks

When I set transparency to a shape, it applies both to the fill color and the stroke color.
What if I need a semi-transparent fill color, but keep the stroke opaque?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving the object a gradient fill and setting the gradient node opacities to 0 is the quickest solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do that in Adobe Fireworks is to work with 2 shapes.
*(not 100% sure about that, if there is someone with more Fireworks knowledge around please correct me, what you would be looking for is something like the Appeareance panel in Adobe Illustrator)*

**This is how you do it with two separate shapes:**

**One shape with no fill color and a 100% Opacity Stroke**,

and then copy/paste the shape,

send it to back(or place it on another layer behind the one with the Stroke shape)

and **for this second shape remove the stroke and add a Fill Color**,

than play with the opacity settings on this shape...

This is what you get(notice that the Stroke color is 100% opaque and the Fill color is transparent):

.

[image]

After you've done all of the above **you can then group the stroke shape with the fill shape** and it kind of acts like one shape...
[in the image above its the orange stroke rectangle and the purple rectangle bellow it, the green circle is just to illustrate the transparency of the fill and the 100% opacity of the stroke of the rectangle group of shapes/strokes]

Comment: Great, try the answer above this one too.. seems legit :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with a single shape.

First, you'll need to create and export 50x50 px black (#000000) square (save it as a PNG8 and place it somewhere you can easily find it again.) This will be used as a texture for the fill.

Now create the vector shape you want to have a transparent fill and solid stroke and assign the stroke and fill colors. For the fill, add a texture, and from the texture list choose "Other..." and navigate to the black PNG8 square previously saved.

When the texture is applied, FW usually defaults to 50% opacity, so it will just look like the fill color got lighter. To make the fill transparent, check the "Transparent" option beneath the texture name.

You can now use the opacity control for the texture to control the opacity of the fill independent of the opacity for the stroke.

Comment: presumably, this is going to scale well because it is a solid fill raster image. Do you know of any adverse side-effects to using a raster image as a fill texture?

Answer (score 1):

Another way, create a vector shape with your desired stroke, on the 'fill option' instead of choosing 'solid fill' choose 'gradient fill' doesn't matter what type or colour if you want a completely transparent fill as you set the opacity on both ends of the gradient to 0. If you require a semi transparent fill then edit the colour and opacity levels to each end of the gradient till you find the required effect.

HTH